# How can I increase or decrease the value when put to a database Firebase RD, javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, put

I have a database in Firebase with current stock. I want to be able to change it with a new value plus input2 or minus input1 new values that I put in in DOM. How can I update the stock with plus or minus the new values?

[image: databse in firebase RD 3 products with 3 cities and its value]

cart.js
//input and select data from DOM in localstorage

```
const select2 = localStorage.getItem('select2')
const select = localStorage.getItem('select')
const input2 = localStorage.getItem('input2')
const input1 = localStorage.getItem('input')
```

//PUT to firebase database when pressed change stock in database
function checkout(){

```
              async function updateSelectValue() {
                try {
                  const baseURL = 'https://paronab-79d88-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
                  const url = baseURL + `product/${select2}/${select}.json`
                  const response = await fetch(url)
                  let data = await response.json()
                 data + input2 
                 data - input1
                  console.log(totalInput)
                  // Send the updated data back to Firebase
                  const updateResponse = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'PUT', // Use PUT to update the entire data
                    body: data,
                    headers: {
                      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                    },
                  });
              
                  if (updateResponse.ok) {
                    console.log('Data updated successfully in Firebase!');
                  } else {
                    console.error('Failed to update data in Firebase.');
                  }
                } catch (error) {
                  console.error('Error while updating data:', error);
                }
              }
              
              // Usage example: Call the updateSelectValue function to update 'select' based on 'select2'
              updateSelectValue('select2', 'select');
            emp
```

tyCart()
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [atomic server-side increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) operation. For the REST API, you can find the syntax [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-server-values).